# Challenges starting jboss v7.1.0 - thunder

Tags: java, jboss7.x

My goal is to migrate my application which is running on jboss v4 to jboss v7.1, my application is completely based on EJB2.0 and so as starting point, I wanted to install jboss v7.1 and get it up and running.

I have downloaded tar.gz file and i have untared it using 7-zip tool, now when i try to run standalone.bat script, I get below mentioned log message:
From errors, it is evident that `C:\Users\ados\Softwares\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\standalone\configuration\mgmt-users.properties and C:\Users\ados\Softwares\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\standalone\configuration\application-users.properties` files are missing.

I have checked in the standalone folder and yes, i do not have those file, my question is:
Are those files present in the distribution, also when i tried to download zip file, i was not successful in getting data and ended up with error message as compressed file does not contain any data.

Also if i try to untar file via cygwin then it ends up with below mentioned error:

```
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/welcome-content/as7_style.css
jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/welcome-content/bkg.gif
jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/welcome-content/documentation.html
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Log message when trying to run standalone.bat files

```
C:\Users\ados\Softwares\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final>ls
LICENSE.txt  README.txt  appclient  bin  bundles  copyright.txt  docs  domain  jboss-modules.jar  modules  standalone  welcome-content


C:\Users\ados\Softwares\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final>cd bin


C:\Users\ados\Softwares\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\bin>ls
add-user.bat    appclient.conf.bat  domain.conf      jboss-cli.bat  standalone.bat       vault.bat
appclient.bat   client              domain.conf.bat  jconsole.bat   standalone.conf      wsconsume.bat
appclient.conf  domain.bat          init.d           jdr.bat        standalone.conf.bat  wsprovide.bat


C:\Users\ados\Softwares\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\bin>standalone.bat
Calling "C:\Users\ados\Softwares\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
===============================================================================


  JBoss Bootstrap Environment


  JBOSS_HOME: C:\Users\ados\Softwares\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final


  JAVA: C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin\java


  JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600
000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=or
g.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml


===============================================================================


13:44:54,475 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
13:44:54,569 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
13:44:54,600 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" starting
13:44:55,084 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
13:44:55,084 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
13:44:55,084 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
13:44:55,099 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.2.GA
13:44:55,115 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
13:44:55,131 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
13:44:55,162 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
13:44:55,162 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
13:44:55,255 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant dr
iver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
13:44:55,271 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
13:44:55,271 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
13:44:55,224 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
13:44:55,209 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
13:44:55,209 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.7.Final)
13:44:55,209 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
13:44:55,396 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.


C:\Users\ados\Softwares\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\bin>standalone.bat
Calling "C:\Users\ados\Softwares\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
===============================================================================


  JBoss Bootstrap Environment


  JBOSS_HOME: C:\Users\ados\Softwares\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final


  JAVA: C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin\java


  JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.prefe
rIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml


===============================================================================


13:46:29,408 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
13:46:29,518 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
13:46:29,549 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" starting
13:46:30,032 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
13:46:30,032 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
13:46:30,048 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
13:46:30,064 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.2.GA
13:46:30,110 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
13:46:30,110 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
13:46:30,095 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.7.Final)
13:46:30,142 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.6.final
13:46:30,064 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
13:46:30,220 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
13:46:30,235 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
13:46:30,251 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
13:46:30,251 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.1.GA
13:46:30,298 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
13:46:30,329 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
13:46:30,344 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
13:46:30,563 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.server.controller.management.security_realm.ManagementRealm.properties_authentication:
org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.server.controller.management.security_realm.ManagementRealm.properties_authentication: JBAS015228: Unable to load properties
        at org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.PropertiesFileLoader.start(PropertiesFileLoader.java:75)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.PropertiesCallbackHandler.start(PropertiesCallbackHandler.java:89)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\ados\Softwares\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\standalone\configuration\mgmt-users.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
        at org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.PropertiesFileLoader.getProperties(PropertiesFileLoader.java:102)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.PropertiesFileLoader.start(PropertiesFileLoader.java:73)
        ... 6 more


13:46:30,563 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.server.controller.management.security_realm.ApplicationRealm.properties_authentication:
org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.server.controller.management.security_realm.ApplicationRealm.properties_authentication: JBAS015228: Unable to load properties
        at org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.PropertiesFileLoader.start(PropertiesFileLoader.java:75)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.PropertiesCallbackHandler.start(PropertiesCallbackHandler.java:89)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\ados\Softwares\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\standalone\configuration\application-users.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
        at org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.PropertiesFileLoader.getProperties(PropertiesFileLoader.java:102)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.PropertiesFileLoader.start(PropertiesFileLoader.java:73)
        ... 6 more


13:46:30,563 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Users\ados\Softwares\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\
standalone\deployments
13:46:30,578 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-1) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8080
13:46:30,641 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
13:46:31,733 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.server.controller.management.security_realm.ManagementRealm.properties_authentication: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
jboss.server.controller.management.security_realm.ManagementRealm.properties_authentication: JBAS015228: Unable to load properties
      service jboss.server.controller.management.security_realm.ApplicationRealm.properties_authentication: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.server.controller.management.security_
realm.ApplicationRealm.properties_authentication: JBAS015228: Unable to load properties


13:46:31,748 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" started (with errors) in 2480ms - Started 126 of 205 services (8 services failed or missing depend
encies, 70 services are passive or on-demand)
```

Comment: Sounds like your downloaded tarball is malformed. Try using wget to download it - `wget http://download.jboss.org/jbossas/7.1/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final.tar.gz`.

Comment: $ wget http://download.jboss.org/jbossas/7.1/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final.tar.gz
--2012-02-27 14:32:22--  http://download.jboss.org/jbossas/7.1/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final.tar.gz
Resolving download.jboss.org (download.jboss.org)... 209.132.182.31
Connecting to download.jboss.org (download.jboss.org)|209.132.182.31|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Comment: @Perception: It is timing out and not giving any outputs.

Comment: @Perception: Are you able to download latest jboss v7.1 server and get it up and running?

Comment: @Perception: Got the same file you mentioned and ran ` tar -zxvf` but still am getting `gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/welcome-content/as7_style.css
jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/welcome-content/bkg.gif`
jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/welcome-content/documentation.html
jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/welcome-content/favicon.ico
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: yea, I just tried to confirm. Takes a while (about 3 mins) to download the ~100MB file. But it expands successfully and the two files you mention are in the `standalone/configuration' folder as expected.

Comment: Try doing a traceroute to 209.132.182.31. Looks like you have a spotty or nonexistent network route mapped to it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8271/discussion-between-perception-and-rachel)

Comment: @Perception: How are you expanding the file, how are you un taring the files

Comment: @Perception: Finally, I was able to get latest jboss v7 related files by doing wget from unix box and then copied it over to windows os and now it is running fine, thanks for continued interest and suggestions.